# How do i pass an item between views with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm playing around with ngRoute and Angular and it seems that I have an issue when trying to chose an item in a view, in order to go to a details page with the coshed item:

```
<h1>Select Item</h1>
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
      <a ng-click="vm.setSelectedItem(item)" ng-href="#/first/{{item.id}}">
           {{item.thing}}
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How come the `vm.selectedItem` is not rendered/shown on the "details" page?

```
var app=angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/first', { 
        templateUrl: 'first.html', 
        controller: 'FirstCtrl',
        controllerAs:'vm' 
    })
    .when('/first/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'firstWithItem.html', 
        controller: 'FirstCtrl',
        controllerAs:'vm'
     })
    .otherwise({ 
        redirectTo: '/first' 
    });
});

app.controller("FirstCtrl", function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.items = [{id:1, thing:"Beer"},{id:2, thing:"Grass"}];
    vm.selectedItem = null;
    vm.setSelectedItem = SetSelectedItem;

    function SetSelectedItem(item) {
        this.selectedItem = item;
    }
});
```

[Link to JSfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/88/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see the change because when you switch views, a new instance of the controller is initiated, and you don't know what you picked.

Since you're using `$routeProvider`, you can use `$routeParams` and use that to fetch your `id` parameter:

```
app.controller("FirstCtrl", function($routeParams) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.items = [{id:1, thing:"Beer"},{id:2, thing:"Grass"}];
    vm.selectedItem = null;

    if ($routeParams.id) {      
        SetSelectedItem($routeParams, vm);
    }

    function SetSelectedItem(item, obj) {
         obj.selectedItem = findItem(item.id, obj.items);
    }

    function findItem(id, array) {
        var res;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
        {
            if (array[i].id == id) {
                return array[i];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/90/)

Answer (score 0):

`FirstCtrl` will be instantiated one more time when the view is changed.

Instead of setting the selectedValue in the controller's scope. Set it on the rootScope and use it.

Here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/89/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the controller initiation from the routes and add it to the top of the application as in this fiddle:
[Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/ymvf7k21/1/)

Then it will be only initiated once.

Edit in JS

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/first', { 
        templateUrl: 'first.html'
    })
        .when('/first/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'firstWithItem.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ 
        redirectTo: '/first' 
   });
});
```

Edit in HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl as vm">
```